Extra padding on screen contents on iOS device using KMP
I have an KMP application using Compose Multiplatform as UI framework. And here's the catch, when I launch app on iOS Simulator, there are some extra space on all four sides.
Here is how it looks:

You can see it on brown header that it doesn't takes while screen space. Any thoughts?
Here is the code from iOS side:
struct ComposeView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        MainViewControllerKt.MainViewController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {}
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ComposeView()
            .ignoresSafeArea()// Compose has own keyboard handler
    }
}

and from CMP side:
@Composable
@Preview
fun App() {
    val vault = LocalVaultProvider.current
    AppTheme {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.safeContentPadding(),
        ) {
            Navigator(
                screen = if (!(vault.vault.existsObject(DEF_TR) && vault.vault.existsObject(DEF_LANG))) OnboardingScreen() else HomeScreen()
            ) {
                FadeTransition(
                    navigator = it, animationSpec = spring(
                        dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioNoBouncy,
                        stiffness = Spring.StiffnessVeryLow,
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
}


I guess that's your safeContentPadding, with compose you don't want to add it for the whole app

Yep, that fixed the situation. Strange behavior imo.
